# edgesForExtendedLayout ignored on iOS9 when using custom animation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, autolayout, ios9

iOS9 seems to ignore destination view controller's `edgesForExtendedLayout`  when implementing custom animation using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, therefore the content ends up below the navigation bar. Any idea why this is happening?

I've hosted an example at https://github.com/nmarkovic04/CustomAnimationTest. Running it on 8.4 and 9.1 shows the difference but you can most likely try any other 8.x and 9.x version.

Running on XCode 7, Swift 2.0.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Related question: "[iOS 9: push/pop view controller broken by edgesForExtendedLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700122/ios-9-push-pop-view-controller-broken-by-edgesforextendedlayout)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this in ViewDidLoad fixes it can you confirm pls :]

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .Top
 self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`

Answer (score 3):

You have to setup proper toViewController's frame. `transitionContext.finalFrame(for:)` will help you. This is my animateTransition(using:) function for fade in/out animation. That one line setting up frame will also fix your shared project.

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        if let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) {

            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
            toViewController.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
            toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           animations: {
                            toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0},
                           completion: { finished in
                            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)})
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, man! Please, take a little improvement for your excellent solution:
```
        let toViewFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
        toView.frame = toViewFrame
        toView.frame.origin.x = presenting ? toView.frame.width : -toView.frame.width
```

Answer (score 1):

Just setting this:

```
  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;
```

Resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Nah, not really. You can try it in the example I've posted. You actually do want to have .None so the content doesn't go under the nav bar.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is awful, but in viewDidLoad() i solved with this:

```
var frame = self.view.frame
frame.origin.y = 64 //The height of status bar + navigation bar
self.view.frame = frame
```

For me the problem comes out the first time my view controller is seen, when i rotate the device the problem is gone.

Comment: For me the first time my view is presented it works fine, just when I present the view again it happens. Rotating landscape and back adjust it.

Comment: When using a `UISplitViewController` in the `collapsed` mode (horizontally Compact) and showing a detail pane, the iOS implementation of `-[showDetailViewController:sender:]` possibly "fakes" `[pushViewController:animated:]` with a custom transition animation, which (incorrectly) ignores `edgesForExtendedLayout`. The only way to QFE this that I found was to `[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{ /* ... */ }]`.