# auto layout issues with multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, autolayout, storyboard

If I create a simple app, with 1 uiviewcontroller, and I embed it in a navigation bar,  the output from the following code

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

print ("...app height is \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)")
print ("...win height is \(self.view.frame.size.height)")
```

}

results in the following:

```
...app height is 1024.0 
...win height is 980.0
```

kind of makes sense, I guess, since the difference in size accounts for the height of the navigation bar, which is 44 points.

Now, I have a problem with an app that makes use of multiple storyboards, and when I transition from one storyboard to the next,  the same code will return:

```
...app height is 1024.0
...win height is 1024.0
```

Strange since both storyboards have a uiview that is embedded in a navigation controller. This is causing auto layout issues, because the size of the navigation bar is not being taken into account.  However, if I rotate the view or move away from it, the problem seems to resolve itself.

So, finally, the question:  How do I ensure proper accounting of the navigation bar so I don't get layout issues when navigation between storyboards?  I've tried forcing setNeedsDisplay() and setNeedsLayout() to no avail.  Any thoughts/ideas/corrections would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your view to go under the navigation bar (i.e. always have the same height as the screen), set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll` (Objc-C), and to do the opposite (no to hide behind any bars): `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone`

**EDIT**

also add `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES`

Sorry for putting all the code in Objective-C, I'm not very good familiar with Swift, however the methods should do the same, they just may be defined with different names

Comment: Thank you @jackal.  Your answer should work, but it seems like my problem comes from a custom transition I set up with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, which breaks the behavior of edgesForExtendedLayout.  I'll explain further below.

Comment: This is a strange one...I'm using a custom animation using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.  and doing this breaks edgesForExtendedLayout.  This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109454/edgesforextendedlayout-ignored-on-ios9-when-using-custom-animation)  describes the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: @Plutovman, everything looks correct to me in that post. I've edited my answer and added a missing part related to opaque bars

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the reason why this is happening, (i.e. the view not registering the presence of a navigation bar to set its sizing).  However, as pointed out on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109454/edgesforextendedlayout-ignored-on-ios9-when-using-custom-animation) thread, changing the size and registration of the view's frame seems to solve the problem.  Adding the following code to viewDidLoad() takes care of the issue:

```
var viewFrame = self.view.frame
let viewNavBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
viewFrame.origin.y = viewNavBarHeight!
viewFrame.size.height = viewFrame.height - viewNavBarHeight!
self.view.frame = viewFrame
```